# How to get Css selector when using java?

Tags: java, css, selenium, selector

I am having trouble in selecting a selector when I am trying to select it as a 'css-selector'

I have this selector:

```
    <div role="button" class="jss300 jss299" tabindex="-1">
        <span class="jss313">system-all</span></div>
    </div>
```

and I am trying to get the css-selector from it, I tried this way:

```
"div[class~='system-paloaltonetworks']"
```

and my need is to get the text from the selector, in this case I want to get "system-paloaltonetworks" into string variable.

hope now the question is clear.

Comment: your question is not clear. Say exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Are you trying to select that span?

Answer (score 1):

`"system-paloaltonetworks"` is the element text, not the class attribute (the class is `jss313`). You can't locate it with `cssSelector` you need to use `xpath` (you should also notice the element has `span` tag, not `div`)

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='system-paloaltonetworks']"));
```

Comment: A nice (and correct:) answer to an (awfully open and unclear) question! :)))

Comment: `div` and `span` all around, why would you `linkText`?

Comment: @tupacshakur Well, it was before you edited the html in your question. Which one is it? `system-all`?

Comment: @Guy _`linkText` works on `span` tags_ ... Can you point me to some documentation please?

Comment: @DebanjanB I remembered it works, but an experiment proved otherwise. Deleted this part.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `class~=` but aren't comparing with the class...

You try: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='jss313']"));`